# Create a list of DataTables from a single DataTable, but grouped by day

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I hope someone can help me with this puzzling question!

In the past I've used the following statement in order to obtain a `List<DataTable>` where each `DataTable` in the list comprises of all the records for each of the distinct names in the "Name" column of the "inputDT" datatable.

In other words, this code outputs a list of tables where each table contains the data for a specific Name:

```
List<DataTable> listOfSerialNumberDataTables = inputDT.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Name")).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList();
```

I now would like to do a similar thing, except I would like to group by a `DateTime` column, where each of the `DataTable`s in `List<DataTable>` comprises of the records which have the same *date* (regardless of time).

So I'm trying to create code which creates a list where a table in the `list<DataTable>` will contain all the data for a specific date.

So for example, one of the tables will contain all the data that is dated 1st Oct 2016, and another table in the list will contain the data for the 3rd Oct, etc. [PS I'm not worried about the *format* of the output of the column - this question is just about get a list of DataTables where the data in them is for a specific *day*.]

[Note - all of the dates are in the table. So I'm not expecting an empty list for a date that is not in the dataTable. Apologies if that's obvious!]

Where I'm at:
After much head-scratching I've come up with something similar to this, but I'm not sure how to finish it off:

```
List<DataTable> listOfDaysForSingleSerialNo = datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Field<DateTime>("DateOfResult"))).<what goes here?>
```

I'm baffled. Can anybody help? Is this actually possible using LINQ?

Thank you in advance for your kind assistance everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to do the exact same thing except on a different column.
So the only thing that should change is the expression going into the `GroupBy()` method:

```
List<DataTable> listOfDaysForSingleSerialNo = datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("DateOfResult").Date).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
The `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` method only works with LINQ to Entities ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx)), so the `GroupBy()` cannot use it. Instead you can just get the `Date` property of the `DateTime`.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for looking. It's not quite the same thing, I want to group on a DateTime column, group by date (not date/time). So I want all the rows for a specific day to be in a dataTable, and so on for all the dates. What you're suggesting would result in only rows with exactly the same date&time being in the same table. This is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: I thought the EntityFunctions.TruncateTime was working for you.
Will update the anwser. Here's a gist example: https://gist.github.com/erikbozic/090ca321946eae6d05fd50deeaa15384

Comment: Excellent - thanks v much, thinkplex. You make it look easy. I was way off the mark with 'EntityFunctions.TruncateTime'. I really appreciate your kind assistance. Thanks again.